# I want to get only the Worksheet names from the List, How to get in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Data:

- [<Worksheet 'Publisher List Approval' id:0>, <Worksheet 'Live Links
  (Jan-March)' id:2076026864>, <Worksheet 'Live Links (April, May,
  June)' id:1550372032>, <Worksheet 'Live Links (Q3: July-Sept)'
  id:937560092>]

Output:

- Publisher List Approval
- Live Links (Jan-March)
- Live Links (April, May, June)
- Live Links (Q3: July-Sept)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

'So first off that Dataset isn't a valid list in python, but assuming it is all strings you can do this.

```py
list_el = ["<Worksheet 'Publisher List Approval' id:0>", "<Worksheet 'Live Links (Jan-March)' id:2076026864>", "<Worksheet 'Live Links (April, May, June)' id:1550372032>", "<Worksheet 'Live Links (Q3: July-Sept)' id:937560092>"]

for each in list_el:
    print(each.split("'")[1])
```

Returns:

```
'Publisher List Approval'
'Live Links (Jan-March)'
'Live Links (April, May, June)'
'Live Links (Q3: July-Sept)'
```

Comment: Colon is not here in Data  <Worksheet 'Publisher List Approval' id:0>